# Euler Characteristic of a hemisphire with a border.

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, geometric-topology

I want to calculate the Euler Characteristic of a Hemisphere with a border, without a border the Hemisphere would be homeomorphic to a Disk, now we make the disjoint union with a flat circunference and we should be able to get the Euler Characteristic by using:

$$\chi(X \cup Y)= \chi(X)+\chi(Y)$$

but somehow this doesn't feel right.

I haven't gotten to Gauss-Bonet Theorem yet, and would like to find it without it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hemisphere without border is an open disk, while hemisphere with a border is a closed disk, they have the same Euler characteristic.

Comment: @lisyarus thank you! Makes sense.